# PHP code not being rendered in browsers

Tags: php, html, rendering

I have a file, manage.php, which contains php code, as depicted below.

Other files are working fine on the same PC and same server (I use WAMP). And the code is working correctly interacting with MySQL databases for a login mechanism on another page...

For some reason the code is not rendered in either FF or Chrome. In chrome, as you can see, the code gets commented out by html comment blocks and nothing prints or is read, etc. I did not write the code like that in my text editor.

I am frustrated. Any ideas?

http://captainscall.site11.com/temp_stuff/why-php.PNG

Here is the full script for manage.php:

```
<?php 
/*
    /admin/index.php
    admin area for Neos Massage
    Made by Douglas Franz, freelance PHP/MySQL/HTML/CSS/JS/jQuery-ist.
*/

session_start();
include('models/auth.php');
include('includes/database.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Neos Massage Admin Area</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/admin.css" />
    </head>

<body>

    <div id="admin_header"> 
        <img src="../images/header-background-restored-flower-no-color.png" style="vertical-align: top;"/>
        <span><b>Admin Area</b><br /><?php if (isset($_SESSION['uName'])) { echo $_SESSION['uName']; } ?></span>
        <div id="border">
        <img src="../images/border.png" width="100%" height="20"/>
        </div>
    </div>  

    <div id="admin_content">

        <h1 style="color: #402d11;">Neos Massage - Manage</h1>
            <hr />
            <a href="index.php?logout">logout</a>
            <br />
            <?php var_dump($_SESSION); echo "this is a test"; ?>
            <?php print "this is a test"; ?>



    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: File extension is PHP?

Comment: @Winston: yes it is. -Asad: just did it

Comment: How do you invoke this file from browser?

Comment: @Winston: with the following address: http://localhost/_clients/NeosMassage/new_version/admin/manage.php on my local machine. Just like any web page

Comment: Dump a new test file called `phpinfo.php` in the root and in the admin folder then try to pull it up in a browser.  Does it render properly for both? Sample phpinfo script: http://www.4webhelp.net/scripts/php/phpinfo.php

Comment: is <hr /> supposed to be <br />?

Comment: @Jim irrelevant.  Look up the `hr` html tag -- horizontal rule.  Even so, doesn't change his PHP issue.

Comment: Does the PHP earlier in the script behave as expected, or does it show up in a comment in the same way?

Comment: @DavidKiger: It shows up in the same way, as a comment, unrendered

Comment: Error logs show anything? Restarted the server?

Comment: It's not the browser that's "not rendering" the PHP, it's the server that is not *executing* the PHP code. Check your server configuration. Start with the simplest test case you can think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you are saying is true, that other `*.php` files run without a problem, my assumption would be that the encoding you are saving the file in is causing the problem.

`<!--?php` <- What Chrome is changing the PHP tag to make me think the encoding of the document is incorrect.

Try saving the file as a new document, or copy and pasting the code into a new document and saving it as a new file. I would bet that fixes your issue.

Comment: yeah, that was the ticket. see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Wow. Okay, so to diagnose it I copied the code in the file and then deleted manage.php altogether.

I then created a new file using the Windows Explorer GUI (the 'normal' way) called manage.php and pasted the code.

Then it worked.

Before I had created manage.php with Windows PowerShell using

```
new-item -type file manage.php
```

I have had similar problems where the encoding of PowerShell is not UTF-8 but Big-Endian or something and it...simply put, messes with things. I suppose this is a rare problem but a good lesson in diagnosing problems.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely not a browser issue: it's an environmental one. Something in WAMP is not set up to execute this page as a PHP script.

Comment: <?php if (isset($_SESSION['uName'])) { echo $_SESSION['uName']; } ?> is not being commented out correct? then this is wrong

Comment: @David Kiger: yeah. But it is indeed only this page. Other pages are fine. I do not know why. The only thing I can think of right now is that I created the file through Windows PowerShell instead of the GUI and so it may have messed up the encoding and the server isn't recognizing it as a PHP file.. iAmClownShoe: that is also being commented out, yes

Comment: @iAmClownShoe See his earlier comment. All PHP is unrendered on this page.

Comment: @khanahk Try using a simple text editor or IDE to create the file

Comment: @Asad: yep. Just did it, and it worked that way (see my answer)